# How to run Software Update w/out root password?

Tags: software-installation, upgrade

I am a `sudo`er on my system, but not a root. I have a Software Update tool (`yumBackend.py`, I think) prompting for specifically `root` password to install system updates. How do I install updates as myself rather than `root`?

My system is CentOS 6.3.

Comment: `sudo yum update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run root commands as regular user you call `sudo` in front of the command like `sudo yum update`.